# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 40: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to load mdl file but it gives me errors. here is my code:

```
def load(clf_file):
    with open(clf_file) as fp:
        clf = c.load(fp)
    return clf

clf = load("model.mdl")
```

after running this its give me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 40: character maps to <undefined>
```

at `clf = load("model.mdl")` line.

I use `encoding='utf8'` at  `with open(clf_file,encoding='utf8') as fp:` this line, but still it gives the same errors.

Comment: The file is apparently encoded with a different encoding. Try `latin-1` for starters.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

Just add 'rb' option to read binary code and it worked.
Soln-

```
with open('response_list/flight_res.json', 'rb') as json_file.
```

Hope this will work.